# Ошибка в отображении элемента с помощью CSS

Tags: css

Банальный пример:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>{TITLE}</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background: #666666;
}
.container #header{
     width:980px;
     height:400px;
     background: blue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
hgjhggggg
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Почему `header` не отображается голубым? В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.container
```

у вас это класс, попробуйте так

```
#container #header{
     width:980px;
     height:400px;
     background: blue;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. А почему это класс? Вот тут же все работает
<div id="container">



  <div id="header">

<center>

    <img src="http://www.igodkb.ru/templates/IGODKBv3/images/logo.gif">

</center> 

  <!-- end #header --></div>

body  {

 font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

 background: #666666;

 margin: 0; 

 padding: 0;



 text-align: center;

 color: #000000;

}

.thrColHybHdr #container { 



 width:980px;

 margin:0 auto;

 background: #FFFFFF;

 text-align: left; 

}

Comment: в CSS обозначение .class - класс,  а #id_element - ид элемента

.thrColHybHdr #container означает что в классе thrColHybHdr будет изменен #container, по коду, всё правильно и нормально